# Graph Theory books/Resources for Mathematical Olympiad

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math, book-recommendation

I'm looking for some Books/Resources about Graph theory for Highschool Math Olympiad. I have some basic knowledge about counting, counting in 2 way, recursion, Bijection but have not learned about Graph yet. I found "Graphs: An Introduction" by Radu Bumbacea. Is that a good book? or there are other one better?

Comment: The title says you want Graph Theory and Combinatorics, but the body says you just want Graph Theory. Please edit for consistency. Then, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94229/graph-theory-resource-for-mathematical-olympiads

Comment: This question better fits the mathematics educators Stack Exchange.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yeah I saw that question, but i feel like the resources are dated. 
Is it still good to use those resources?, since I think the problem nowaday are diffrent from 2011?

Comment: As you saw that earlier question, you should have linked to it in your question, and you should have provided justification for asking your question.

Answer (score 1):

"A walk through combinatorics : An Introduction to Enumeration and Graph Theory" by Miklós Bóna.

Well, the book doesn't mention that it's specifically for Olympiad but the problems are nice and the textbook is enjoyable. Ths book covers more material than required, but uhm till Chapter III will do for you I guess. Or just Chapter III specifically for Graph theory.

If you just need some familiarity with graph theory, then "The art and craft of problem solving" by Paul zeitz, chapter 4 and "The Art of Problem Solving, Volume 2 and Beyond" by Richard Rusczyk Sandor Lehoczky, chapter 25  might suit your purposes.